# Getting a specified user from Graph API

Tags: c#, azure-ad-graph-api

How does one return a single specified user via Graph API?

I'm able to return all users, but need to acquire a single user via CLI arguments.

Comment: It clearly states how to get one user [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#examples).

Comment: Yes, but not in C#, only in an HTTP Request.

Comment: In which Namespace `GraphServiceClient` exist ?

Comment: Microsoft.Graph

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out, unfortunately it isn't documented anywhere, but it does allow filtering.

```
var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().Filter($"DisplayName eq '{name}'").GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the OID of your user, you can more simply do this:

```
var user = await graphClient.Users[OID].Request().GetAsync();
```